# What is the range that the random function can return?

Tags: c++, function, math, random, floating-point

```
int nextInt(int n) {
    return rand() / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) * n;
}
```

I find someone write the above function(`nextInt`) and he said `nextInt` returns a random int in [0, n - 1], but I think `nextInt` returns a random int in [0, n]. I wonder who is right and why?

Comment: Short Video by Mr. STL: __rand() Considered Harmful__ - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful  Answers your question and more.

Comment: So what is the conclusion?

Comment: Either watch it or don't - summarising all that is wrong (with `rand`) is what the video is about.  Your specific question start about 6:10. quote: _"... Hilariously non-uniform..."_

Comment: If i run this in Visual Studio (where `RAND_MAX` is only `32767`), I get `n` as a result fairly quickly.

Comment: Actually, such details can be easily found in the doc. e.g. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand): _Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (**0 and RAND_MAX included**)._ (Emphasize mine.)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the range that the random function can return?

Standard specifies it to be [0, RAND_MAX] (inclusive).

> I wonder who is right and why?

You are. nextInt can technically return n, but it has very small chance to do so. Only when rand() returns RAND_MAX does that happen (maybe some other near values in theoretical case where the range of int isn't exactly representable by double, as per comments).

Comment: Technically I guess this assumes that `double` can exactly represent `RAND_MAX`. For IEEE 64 bit floats that's certainly the case but the standard leaves floating point implementation largely unspecified.

Comment: I believe the required check would be `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559 && std::numeric_limits<double>::digits >= std::numeric_limits<int>::digits`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

`rand()` returns a value in `[0, RAND_MAX]`, thus the function returns a value in `[0, n]`.

nextInt will return a random number, but it is not using a laplacian distribution to generate those; because `n` is less likely to occur than other numbers from `[0, n]`

Whether or not this is a problem depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) that:
Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (***0 and RAND_MAX included***). So `nextInt` returns a random int in [0, n].

Reason: When `rand()` return value equal to `RAND_MAX` then:
RAND_MAX / RAND_MAX * n = n